# jquery function call when clicking blank space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know how to call the function if some one click in blank space in the jsp page.

I tried the following code but it's not working how I want.

Can any one tell me how to do this?

```
jQuery("*:not(select)").click(function(){

    alert("clck");
    //some code here

    });
```

Here I tried whenever I click out side the select box the function will call.

If I click the select box it won't call, but this function is called all the time.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because of event propagation so stop event bubbling

Comment: @A.Wolff then how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably do it something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target === document || e.target.tagName === "BODY" || e.target.tagName === "HTML") {
        // Clicked on blank space
    }
});
```

That hooks the `click` event on `document` and then checks to see if the click *originated* on the document (or the `body` or `html` elements). If it did, the user clicked in "blank space" (e.g., not on some other element within the document).

Comment: Doesn't @Vaibhav's answer enough check?

Comment: @A.Wolff: `body` doesn't always fill the viewport.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure will work in all browsers but in chrome.

```
$('body').click( function (e) { 
    if ( e.target == this ) 
        alert('clck'); 
});
```

Comment: @KVK You sure? Try it again. Mozilla doesn't pass by default `event` object BUT here this answer is explecitely passing variable `e` to refers to event

Comment: `T.J. Crowder` made a good point in his answer regarding BODY not always filling all document viewport

Answer (score 0):

If you want a special item to be not included in the click try this

```
$('#itemtobeexcluded').on('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Then for whole document:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
 // function body
});
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this will work

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) { 

        alert('clck'); 
});
```